# I get an error when I'm trying to do a time-constrained cluster in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to do a chronological cluster (time constrained clustering), so I'm using the package const.clust from R. I have to construct a matrix of connexions, so I use the function contiguity.mat for that. It constructs a contiguity matrix from the data read in a file of connexions between points. In my case, these points are sampler dates, that aren't equispaced. I'm not sure if contiguity.mat is the correct function because in all the examples that I found the points were coordinates (for do a constrained space clustering), not dates.

Taking it into account, when I run the contiguitiy.mat the R answers me with an error.

```
library(mvpart)
library(const.clust)

from<-abun0[1:50,1]
from<-as.Date(from)
from<-data.frame(from)
to<- abun0[2:51,1]
to<- as.Date(to)
to<-data.frame(to)
from.to<-cbind(from,to)
links.mat.spp <- contiguity.mat(from.to, 51)
```

Error in contiguity.mat(from.to, 51) : Error: 'From' > n

Other option:

```
from<-abun0[1:50,1]
from<-as.Date(from)
from<-data.frame(from)
to<- abun0[2:51,1]
to<- as.Date(to)
to<-data.frame(to)
from.to<-cbind(from,to
from.to<-as.matrix(from.to)
links.mat.spp <- contiguity.mat(from.to, 51)
```

Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, j, i, value = 1) : 
  no 'dimnames' attribute for array

I don't understand what I have to do now. Please, can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the `const.clust`-package or `contiguity.mat`, but are you sure you need `51` as the second argument? Because the `from.to`-matrix is only 50 rows as you've constructed it now.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know, but when you see the help in R about contiguity.mat there is an example and the matrix is constructed in this way. However, I tried with 50 rows just in case, and the program answers with the same error.